# Can i install ubuntu on a separate ssd and boot without a prompt

Tags: boot, dual-boot, ssd

I use linux 99% of the time. I would like to install ubuntu on a spare ssd drive on my machine and have it boot without needing a prompt from boot manager

I also would like to be able to send a magic packet to wake the machine but i think this is something i can achieve from ubuntu network manager itself.

So to clarify i would like to boot straight to ubuntu, But still have ability to boot into windows when i need to i think its `shift` key to get back to boot manager?

Also i will be encrypting the disk from installation will this interfere with booting because it will ask for a password prompt?

I will be accessing this machine from ssh most of the time.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you use an external ssd, isn't?
You could change the bootorder in de bios and set the external disk before the internal disk.

I think this will help you and  u can use encryption enabled, because on that moment the system is allready using the disk